# PHP & WordPress - Get posts by filtering by Categories AND custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and I've managed to build most of a full custom theme for wordpress on my own.

But the tricky stuff is starting to show its tail, and I've spent the last days stuck on Taxonomies. I just managed to put a code for registering a custom Taxonomy to sort my articles by level of difficulty.

Now I need to work on a taxonomy.php (maybe I'm wrong here) page template where it will display articles by their Category (ex : "Design")  AND  the difficulty (ex : "Advanced") the reader will choose.

Frankly, staying on this and searching all the web, trying things and failing, plus me not being that good has somewhat burnt my brain, and I have no clue about how to do it! 
(well no, I guess it has something to do with the post query loop and the taxonomy term and the category term  being in the link to the page (maybe i'm wrong here too, probably !)

Comment: [This page in the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies) describes naming conventions for these types of templates. Beyond that, you just need to use a standard loop within the template: `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ): the_post();`

Comment: If you use [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) you can use both `tax_query` and `category` parameters to filter.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, I'll be looking into that. But if anyone has an example with some explanations it will be very welcomed !